# string to date with Timezone in python 3.3

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I am able to convert the below date time if I trim of the timezone data by using the code:

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(cc.text[:25],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

However, when I use %z or %Z along with the time zone data, I am receiving the below error, could you please make me understand where I am going wrong, I am using python 3.3 and %z should work in it.

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(cc.text,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '2014-09-16T19:26:18.5455599+05:30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't fit the code you said you tried; the error message states you used `%Z` (capital Z).

Comment: I tried both %Z, and %z, just gave it a try, %z is when for value provided as number :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

- the length of the miliseconds component has 7 digits, but Python expects 6.
- the timezone offset contains a `:` colon.

Removing those two extra characters makes `strptime()` work:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> cctext = '2014-09-16T19:26:18.5455599+05:30'
>>> cctext[:-7] + cctext[-6:-3] + cctext[-2:]
'2014-09-16T19:26:18.545559+0530'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(cctext[:-7] + cctext[-6:-3] + cctext[-2:], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 16, 19, 26, 18, 545559, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 19800)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains why I did not get the result even though I removed last colon; this is a ISO format, yet don't know why python should not consider the 7th millisecond.

Comment: @surpavan: datetime object has only microsecond precision. It has to  drop 900 nanoseconds (or round some other way). You could submit the feature request (round automatically or store more digits) on [Python Issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org/)

Comment: @surpavan: anything beyond 6 digits is no longer microseconds; a microsecond us 0.000001 second; the 7th decimal is tens of microseconds or 100 nanoseconds. A datetime object cannot support anything smaller than one microsecond. ISO8601 may not limit the number of decimals but does state the communicating parties need to agree on a limit.

Comment: @surpavan: related: [datetime: add ability to parse RFC 3339 dates and times](http://bugs.python.org/issue15873)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I am from VB.net, I never new this depth, the Visual Studios and .Net are so greatly integrated that they keep me in blind, but after coming to python, just a few weeks of span, I learned a great deal of true variables, objects and in depth of coding issues, and this is a positive comment. I must say, every must start learning coding starting from python :D.  Thank you.